# Extending identity User to create a profile

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, one-to-one, ef-core-2.0

I created a class to represent a user profile. It's also linked to the default asp.net core applicationUser generated:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
    public string UserProfileId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Status { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

My question is, do I still need to create a DbSet for ApplicationUser?

```
public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }

public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; } //DO I NEED THIS?
```

Comment: this line looks incorrect `public virtual ApplicationUser User`

Comment: @viveknuna How so? I'm not getting any error readings on my compiler.

Comment: It is not necessary since when EF Core creates entity for UserProfile it will add ApplicationUser to the model too. Its upto you if you want DbSet or not.